# cordova 1.7.0 set info error

Tags: ios5, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using cordova 1.7.0. My app is running fine in simulator but a message comes like

```
Error: executing module function 'setInfo' in module 'cordova/plugin/ios/device'. Have you included the iOS version of the cordova-1.7.0.js file?
```

I have included

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="[location of cordova.ios(for ios)]"></script>
```

in index.html but did not work.Plz help.

Answer (score 1):

there must be something wrong with the path to the js. 
The index.html file is read?
Is your www folder maybe a group instead of a [reference folder](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/img/guide/getting-started/ios/create-folder-reference.png)?

**Go [step by step](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS)**

Comment: i have done mistake in referencing folder, now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when the cordova file is not properly available when the page is loaded. You can check that it is referencing properly by opening the index.html (or your start page) in the Chrome and check in Inspect Element that all the resources are loaded and there are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem, just follow steps in picture [image: You need to check this again]